# Comparing against DataTable row value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datatable

I'm needing to create a unit test for a new method I have created. Right now, I'm having an issue comparing my actual result with my desired result.

The method in question is:

```
public DataTable UniformDateFormat(DataTable durations, string targetColumn)
{

    foreach (DataRow row in durations.Rows)
     {
         if (row[targetColumn].ToString().Length > 0)
          {
              DateTime conv = DateTime.Parse(row[targetColumn].ToString());
          }
     }

     return durations;
}
```

This method is simply checking for a specific column and then converts the date value found within each cell of the column (it's an excel sheet) and converts them to something more uniform.

My test code for it is this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Reporting Date");

table.Rows.Add("12-06-2007");
test = new DurationData(excelConfig);

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    result = row["Reporting Date"].ToString();

}
// the test I want to run
if (table.Columns.Contains("Reporting Date"))
{
     result = test.UniformDateFormat(table, "Reporting Date").ToString();
     Assert.AreSame("2007-06-12", result);
     Console.Write("here");
}
```

When I run this test code I get the following output:

> Message: Expected: same as "2007-06-12" But was: string.Empty

What do I need to modify in order to run my test properly?

Comment: The `UniformDateFormat` method is strange, it basically does nothing but trying to convert strings to datetimes without assigning those datetimes no any variable. Apart from that `UniformDateFormat` returns a `DataTable` and `ToString` just returns the table's `TableName` property(+ `DisplayExpressio`). Ofcourse that's not a date.

Comment: Are you sure that the method `UniformDateFormat` as the same code as you posted and it is part of larger framework? The method does not do anything meaningful and returns the same datatable which is passed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling ...

```
 result = test.UniformDateFormat(table, "Reporting Date").ToString();
 Assert.AreSame("2007-06-12", result);
```

... you take a complete DataTable and call `.ToString()` on it. This is simply returning its table name (property `.TableName`) which is not set in your sample. So you compare a date string with an empty string - that's exactly what the error message tells.

As far as I can see, that method `UniformDateFormat` just formats the date values. You should not use its return values but instead loop through the data rows and compare the values in the column "Reporting Date" with your date string.

I see you tried anything like that but your first loop ends to early. Check it like this:

```
// format the dates BEFORE the loop
test.UniformDateFormat(table, "Reporting Date");

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    // assert the date values for each row
    string dateValue = row["Reporting Date"].ToString();
    Assert.AreSame("2007-06-12", dateValue);
}
```

However, be aware that the method `UniformDateFormat` will not do anything to the DataTable because it just converts date values but does not write them back.

Comment: The new method is part of a larger frame work I can not amend. How can I get my result string to be the value of the only row in the datatable? It's that call I'm trying to make